# How to add a donation function in a smart contract

Tags: erc-20

How would I add a donation function to this type of smart contract
https://etherscan.io/address/0x39E5BD6AE0f2aA9240D2ae7fBF49e36F05dd339F#code

Basically, what I would like to do is have a small fee added to the airdrop function so that when someone claims a small donation is made as part of the transaction (say 0.00001 ETH or similar).  To use the GetAirdop function it is recommended to use 200,000 GAS. It will be clearly stated that is the case and I thought a good way for a charity based token to raise funding whilst giving away tokens.

Answer (score 0):

You need to do the following:

- Make the function `payable`
- `require` that the `msg.value` is greater than or equal to your required "donation" amount

Like so:

```
function getAirdrop() canGetAirdrop payable returns (bool) {
    require(msg.value >= 0.00001 ether);
    if (isAirdropAddress[msg.sender]) revert();
    if (AirdropReward < 10000)  AirdropReward = 10000;
    isAirdropAddress[msg.sender] = true;
    balances[msg.sender] += AirdropReward;
    AirRewardTotalSupply += AirdropReward;
    Transfer(this, msg.sender, AirdropReward);
    delete transferIns[msg.sender];
    transferIns[msg.sender].push(transferInStruct(uint128(balances[msg.sender]),uint64(now)));

    AirdropMined(msg.sender, AirdropReward);
    AirdropReward -=10000;
    return true;
}
```

You can find these details in Lesson 4 of the [CryptoZombies tutorial](http://shawntabrizi.com/crypto/shawn-notes-cryptozombies-lessons-1-5-in-solidity/).

Comment: Great thanks for the fast reply and help, I will give it a try!

Comment: That function is giving me the following error: TypeError: Overriding function changes state mutability from "nonpayable" to "payable".
    function getAirdrop() canGetAirdrop payable returns (bool) {
Would it be better if it was added to the main transfer function and let's say just charged a fix 1% of the gas to the owner's address?

Comment: Gas and Ether which can be taken from a transaction are different. You cannot have your contract funnel funds from the Gas amount. Any funds your contract can capture has to come from the `msg.value` sent in the transaction. The error message you are getting is because you also need to add the `payable` keyword to the `PoSTokenStandard` which defines `function getAirdrop() returns (bool);`. Note that this does change the standard, but you seem to want to do your own thing.

Comment: Thanks for all your help, that suggestion and code is all working.  However, I take your point about Gas & Eth.  I think it would be clearer to the token holder/airdrop participant if there was a separate option to donate.  I'll go on the hunt for that instead :)